Why is my pup toileting inside when im not home or at night time
So, I have toilet trained my pup to go outside to go toilet. I have fitted a dog flap in the back door in which he uses no problem.
He uses this absolutely fine during the daytime to go toilet, but the thing is is that when I'm not home or at night, he still uses the dog flap but goes toilet inside. I know this as I see this on a camera I've fitted to keep check on him, he is 14 weeks old.
I'm just struggling to know why this is happening, so any answers to this will be very helpful.
Thanks

How long are you typically away?

This question is similar to: Puppy will not use dog door at night. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
